# Displaying the Json result in Table with some logic

Tags: javascript, html, json, aurelia

i have an requirement to display some Json data in Html table using Auralia js.

Hear is my Json data

```
[{
    "Key": "Name",
    "value": "Sriram",
    "order": "01"
  }, {
    "Key": "Email",
    "value": "sriram@gmail",
    "order": "02"
  }, {
    "Key": "Genader",
    "value": "male",
    "order": "03"
  }, {
    "Key": "DOB",
    "value": "01-01-88",
    "order": "04"
  }, {
    "Key": "MobileNo",
    "value": "999999999",
    "order": "05"
  }, "Key": "Address", "value": "", "order": "06"
}]
```

Now i need to show this table where all "order" evens at one side and odds at other side

[image]

Is there any simple way to achive this in using Aurelia js/JavaScript

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The correct way to accomplish this goal in Aurelia is to use a Value Converter to filter the collection. You could create a single value converter that can do both odds and evens, but I think the code is more readable by creating two value converters. I've modified @LStarky's solution to show how to do this:

Runable gist: https://gist.run?id=1a66d5495314b06e378062610bd8da80**

**app.html**

```html
<template>
  <div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <h1>Bootstrap Method (Responsive)</h1>
    <p><i>The second column will wrap down below on smaller screens... 
    if you see it in one column, try widening the screen</i></p>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-6">
        <div repeat.for="field of myData | odds">
          <p><b>${field.Key}:</b> ${field.value}</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-6">
        <div repeat.for="field of myData | evens">
          <p><b>${field.Key}:</b> ${field.value}</p>
        </div>
      </td>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

**app.js**

```js
export class App {
  myData = [{
      "Key": "Name",
      "value": "Sriram",
      "order": "01"
    }, {
      "Key": "Email",
      "value": "sriram@gmail",
      "order": "02"
    }, {
      "Key": "Genader",
      "value": "male",
      "order": "03"
    }, {
      "Key": "DOB",
      "value": "01-01-88",
      "order": "04"
    }, {
      "Key": "MobileNo",
      "value": "999999999",
      "order": "05"
    }, "Key": "Address", "value": "", "order": "06"
  }];
}

export class EvensValueConverter {
  toView(value) {
    return value.filter( x => parseInt(x.order) % 2 === 0 );
  }
}

export class OddsValueConverter {
  toView(value) {
    return value.filter( x => parseInt(x.order) % 2 === 1 );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you both out you @Ashily and LStarky.

Comment: @Ashily , i am unable to run your Runable gist :(

Answer (score 1):

Here's the Aurelia solution:

Working Demo: 
https://gist.run/?id=20495ff4f507472936b0ae5c99058bac

**app.js**

```
export class App {
  myData =  [{"Key":"Name","value":"Sriram","order":"01"},{"Key":"Email","value":"sriram@gmail","order":"02"},{"Key":"Genader","value":"male","order":"03"},{"Key":"DOB","value":"01-01-88","order":"04"},{"Key":"MobileNo","value":"999999999","order":"05"},{"Key":"Address","value":"","order":"06"}];
}
```

**app.html:**

```
<h1>Table Method</h1>
<table width="100%">
  <td>
    <div repeat.for="field of myData" if.bind="field.order % 2">
      ${field.Key}: ${field.value}
    </div>
  </td>
  <td>
    <div repeat.for="field of myData" if.bind="!(field.order % 2)">
      ${field.Key}: ${field.value}
    </div>
  </td>
</table>
```

Comment: I'm not a fan of this solution. I'd prefer if you created a ValueConverter that would filter it. I'm gonna edit your answer to do this :-)

Comment: That makes sense... I hadn't thought of that but clearly it's better because it only cycles through the appropriate keys.

Comment: @Sriram, you should choose Ashley Grant's answer.  It's a much better approach to the evens/odds than mine.

Answer (score 0):

if you can use angularJS, here is a solution..may be you may find a similar logic in Aurelia js too :-

in your controller -

```
app.controller("myController", function($scope){
  $scope.myData = [{"Key":"Name","value":"Sriram","order":"01"},{"Key":"Email","value":"sriram@gmail","order":"02"},{"Key":"Genader","value":"male","order":"03"},{"Key":"DOB","value":"01-01-88","order":"04"},{"Key":"MobileNo","value":"999999999","order":"05"},"Key":"Address","value":"","order":"06"}];
});
```

And your html -

```
<div style="display: inline;">
  <div ng-repeat="(k,v) in myData" ng-if="$index % 2 == 0" style="float:left">
     {{k}}:{{v}}
  </div>
  <div ng-repeat="(k,v) in myData" ng-if="$index % 2 == 1" style="float:right">
     {{k}}:{{v}}
  </div>
</div>
```